# $t$-test for two groups when means are equal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a sample data from two different groups. I want to run independent samples $t$-test on it, but the problem I am facing is that both groups have equal means (i.e. 7) and so the result that is generated is $p=1$ with $t=0.00$. How to conduct the test properly?

```
Mechanism   Shares
Pull    12
Pull    3
Pull    9
Pull    4
Pull    14
Pull    6
Pull    1
Push    8
Push    6
Push    0
Push    5
Push    12
Push    7
Push    11
```

Comment: If both means are the same what else behaviour would you expect of $t$-test? Their difference is *exactly* zero, so there is no point in checking if it "statistically" differs from zero.

Comment: The t-test is correct. It is testing if the difference between two means is statistically significant. When there is no actual difference between the means they also can't be statistically significant. Additionally, you have very little data.

Comment: @stjep does no actual difference between both means suggest that i should stick with my null hypothesis as they are statistically insignificant.?

Comment: @Tim how should u use results in such cases to satisfy or neglect null hypothesis?

Comment: @Rehan is 1 < 0.05 (or any other threshold of your choice) ?

Comment: @Tim no it's not.

Comment: So you cannot reject null hypothesis that the means do not differ.

Comment: The same issue arose here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195470/strange-significant-test-results-with-scipy Although statistical people are prone to assert that no evidence confirms a null hypothesis, here of zero difference between means, it is necessarily true that no data could be more consistent with that hypothesis than data showing zero difference between sample means.

Comment: @Rehan, you are unable to reject the null hypothesis. This does not mean that the null is true, only that you have not rejected it. If you collected a lot more data you may end up with means that are different and would be sufficient to reject the null with a t test.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer?  It's obviously not whether the means differ since you already know they don't.  Since the $t$ test is looking at means, it's the wrong test in this situation.  If you could be more clear about what kind of difference you're trying to detect, someone might be able to suggest an alternative procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scenario that you are describing, you are comparing two means. You are doing so by looking at their difference if it is different than zero. In your case, since the means are *exactly equal*, you know that their difference is *exactly zero*. Hypothesis test appropriately returns $p$-value equal to one, so you cannot reject null hypothesis because obviously $p = 1 \not\le 0.05$ (or any other threshold value).

However this is something that you knew already before conducting the test. Think of it in terms of confidence intervals for means of both groups. No matter how wide or narrow would they be (i.e. how uncertain would you be about your estimates) they would *always* cross since the means are the same and the intervals are centred around means (that is true also for unsymmetrical intervals). Hypothesis test would not tell you anything more than this.

Comment: The Confidence Intervals for each mean values are such that one of them contais the other
(because the amplitudes are a direct function of the standard errors).
Tim got a correct answer.